# Remove Empty tags in XML using plain python without lxml library

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing

My use case is to remove empty tags in an XML using simple plain python 2.7. No extra lxml library is available.

Sample Code:

```
<ArML>
    <MsgHeader>
        <Deal>
            <Attribute>
                <Name>First</Name>
                <Value>10</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
                <Name>Second</Name>
                <Value></Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
                <Name>Third</Name>
                <Value></Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
                <Name>Fourth</Name>
                <Value>40</Value>
            </Attribute>
        </Deal>
    </MsgHeader>
    <MsgHeader>
        <Deal>
            <Attribute>
                <Name>Fifth</Name>
                <Value>10</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
                <Name>Sixth</Name>
                <Value></Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
                <Name>Seventh</Name>
                <Value>70</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
                <Name>Eight</Name>
                <Value></Value>
            </Attribute>
        </Deal>
    </MsgHeader>
</ArML>
```

I am using the below code, but it is not working properly for all the empty tags. Please help.

```
for elem in root.iter('MsgHeader'):
Deal = root.find("./MsgHeader/Deal")
empty = root.find("./MsgHeader/Deal/Attribute/[Value='']")
Deal.remove(empty)
print(ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8').decode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Your code searches for `Attribute` with an empty `Value` and removes that. To only search for the empty Values, use `./MsgHeader/Deal/Attribute/Value[not(text())]`.

Comment: your logic is giving this error.................  

 selector = _cache[cache_key]
KeyError: ('./MsgHeader/Deal/Attribute/Value[not(text())]', None)

..........................Can you please implement it for the above xml data.

Comment: I believe that without using extra library like lxml etc., this requirement might not be possible, but as an implementation specialist i found a work-around for this.
You can replace your empty string with the 'NULL' keyword and then remove the line altogether where ever you find 'NULL' in the XML.